# Heat pump COP Improvement, would this work?

Tags: thermodynamics

The coefficient of performance of a heat pump is largely determined by how much heat can be added to the refrigerant vapour between the expansion valve (maybe -40) and the compressor, as it passes through the evaporator.
If the expansion valve were replaced by a pressure relief valve (to maintain the condenser pressure/temperature) then as the pressure relief valve opens, the still warm/still high pressure refrigerant in a vapour/liquid state were allowed to enter a reservoir of liquid gas in the evaporator, it would soon cool down/reduce pressure as it mixes with the cold evaporating reservoir of liquid gas, but it would be enhancing the temperature in the evaporator, not reducing it.
Would this work?

Comment: As long as you are specifically trying to generate an appreciable difference in any intensive variable, here you choose a pressure difference and temperature difference as the highly pressurised hot vapour slams into lower pressure cold vapour, you will be much less efficient than using the difference to extract work via a better cycle. i.e. what you have proposed is necessarily going to do worse than not doing it. In fact, reversing your suggestion is one of the things that James Watt originally improved the engine by.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.